# Strange error when reading txt files

Tags: c++

Edit: I got the error. I need to put "books/" before the file name.

I'm reading the files names from a directory and then opening these files one by one.

I read the file and print its contents.

I have written a C++ code for this but its not working. I am not able to find any errors in it.

What am I doing wrong ?

My code -

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <dirent.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    DIR *dirp;
    struct dirent *dp;


    if ((dirp = opendir("books")) == NULL) {
        perror("couldn't open '.'");
        return 0;
    }


    do {
        errno = 0;
        if ((dp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {        

            if(strlen(dp->d_name)>4){

                string str; 
                int count=0;

                ifstream in(dp->d_name);
                //cout<<dp->d_name<<"....."<<endl;
                while (!in.eof() && count<100) {
                    in >>str;
                    cout<<str;
                    count++;
                }

                in.close();
            }

        }
    } while (dp != NULL);


    if (errno != 0)
        perror("error reading directory");

    (void) closedir(dirp);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I got the error. I need to put "books/" before the file name.

Comment: Need more precision than "doesn't work".  What *exactly* is it doing?

Comment: Also, you normally have to specify more than "books". Like, an actual full path.

Comment: It's not printing anything. Anyways I got the error. I need to put "books/" before the file name.